# Few buttons in LinearLayout with equal width and single line text

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to have few button with the same width in LinearLayout

My code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true" >
    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="button" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="button with long title" />
</LinearLayout></RelativeLayout>
```

But in the result (checked in eclipse design tool) button with longer text  become multiline or have ecllipsize!

What should i do to have button with equal width and single line full text. The button width should fit whith the longest title.

Any ideas?

---

I solved it by coding but continue to be interested in declarative solution

Comment: Do you want to fill the width of the screen with the buttons?

Comment: No, I want to place the block of few buttons in center of screen. The buttons should have equal width according to the longest button title

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="button" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="button with long title" />
</LinearLayout>
```

You have to just put few properties i.e. `android:singleLine="true"` & `android:gravity="center"` as in answer. By this, you get `button`s of equal size and also in single line only.

Comment: The buttons are of equal size and  in single line, but only with ecllipsize. I need full text!

Comment: If you need full text then, set `android:singleLine:false` or decrease `android:textSize`. or check the edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_centerInParent="true" >

<Button
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="button" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="button with long title
</LinearLayout>
```

This will make sure that even if the second button text goes to the second line, the first copies the height and they end up looking similar.

Comment: but i have a lot of free place and need to have single line titles

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true" >
    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="button" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="button with long title" />
</LinearLayout></RelativeLayout>
```